# navbar menu on-click doesnt collapse when clicked on the menu icon

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Two issues related to bootstrap that is not working for me.

1. When I click on the hamburger icon on the mobile view. It opens up the menu fine, however whenever I click on the hamburger icon again to close it doesn't close, it stays open always.
2. When I hover over the menu links under the hamburger, when it opens up it doesn't hover and change the color of the links.  Kindly assist to get this to working.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  color: red;
  font-weight: Italic;
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: green;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #380707;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav{
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #D4AC0D!important
}

.navbar-toggler{
  background-color: brown;
}

.nav-item > a:hover {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}


.bg-dark{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.nav-link > a:hover {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: green;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  color:white !important;
}

.navbar.collapse {
  display:none;
}

.navbar.show {
  background:white !important;
}

.collapse {
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="#">My Website</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gallery" routerLinkActive="">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/products" routerLinkActive="">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contactus" routerLinkActive="">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So a couple things. I moved your snippet to the code editor in your post to provide the bootstrap css reference that matches your version. Viewing here it works fine and would expand/collapse as expected from the hamburger icon. So I'm not able to reproduce your first part of your question.

The second part though, is your selector specificity and how your css classes are organized. Which I wasn't sure if that's intentional, but your `color: red` etc aren't getting changed to that color because you also have the bootstrap `.active` class on each, which it probably shouldn't be but I didn't want to assume.

So if you see the example below where I changed your `li` hover to change your anchor color with the `!important` flag it works because it now overrides the `active` class color. I also commented out another of your attempts because it would have been redundant. I'd recommend getting a bit more familiar with specificity and css selectors to avoid these kinds of issues in the future.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  color: red;
  font-weight: Italic;
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: green;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #380707;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav{
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #D4AC0D!important
}

.navbar-toggler{
  background-color: brown;
}

.nav-item:hover > .nav-link {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  font-family:  Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}


.bg-dark{
  background-color: aqua;
}
/*
.nav-link > a:hover {
  font-family: Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: green;
}
*/

.navbar-toggler {
  color:white !important;
}

.navbar.collapse {
  display:none;
}

.navbar.show {
  background:white !important;
}

.collapse {
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="#">My Website</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gallery" routerLinkActive="">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/products" routerLinkActive="">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contactus" routerLinkActive="">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris W, for correcting the format. not sure how its working in code snippet whereas in my local its not working. when i do inspect on the humburger icon and when i click on it, the class immediately changes from `class="navbar-collapse collapsing" to class="navbar-collapse collapse show" ` and `aria-expanded="true"` always stays at true in inspect mode. which means its always in open mode only.

Comment: And the same issue with the links under the menu, its working in code snippet and its not working in my local. in the landscape mode the link color change is working fine, only when in the mobile mode, under the humburger menu, it doesnt hover to red, color remains constant. not sure what wrong am i doing.

Comment: If it's genuinely "mobile mode" then the hover event doesn't really exist and it's just click event since you only hover with a mouse and not your thumb. So that may be the issue you're seeing. As for the expand/collapse thing we'd need to see a reproducible example of it **not** working to troubleshoot that issue since it works here as expected as long as you have the bootstrap script/css references right.